# Canon 16-35 f/2.8L II zoom ring noise

Tags: canon, zoom, wide-angle

I just bought this lens. Out of the box, it makes a little noise while turning the zoom ring left and right (different from the other lenses I have, almost a metallic kind of noise).

It looks like it's coming from the moving part on top of the lens.

Is it normal, or did I get a bad copy?

Comment: Without hearing what you are it is hard to say. What other lenses do you have that you are comparing it to?

Comment: I have the 70-200 2.8, 50 1.2 and 100 2.8 macro

Comment: Despite the noise, is ring moving relatively freely or you feel it's tight?

Comment: We need more information. How loud is the sound? Are you putting your ear right up to the lens barrel, or can you clearly hear it even holding the lens at arms length? Does it actually sound "bad", or is it just a noise that otherwise seems benign?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a metallic sound.  Maybe a little sound from parts of the inner barrel moving against the outer barrel.  You may have a bad copy that escaped Canon QA.